# Java - Why empty output on console?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, collections, console

I've got a problem here:

I was asked to create a collection of random lottery numbers. These numbers should then be ordered from low to high and duplicates shouldn't be put out on the console.

It's working so far but the console throws an empty output when the size of the collection is not == 6. I gave an else instruction that the method should then be executed again.

Hope anybody understands and can help.

Thank you!

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Lotto {
    public static Collection<Integer> tippen() {
        List<Integer> liste = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (liste.size() < 6) {
            liste.add((int) (Math.random()*49+1));
        }       

        Collections.sort(liste);

        LinkedHashSet<Integer> lottotipp = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(liste);
        liste.clear();
        liste.addAll(lottotipp);

        return lottotipp;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Collection<Integer> zahlen = tippen();

        if (zahlen.size() == 6) {   
            System.out.println("Ihr Tipp: " + zahlen);
        } else {
            tippen();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @martijnn2008 `zahlen.size() != 0`, the `tippen()` method will never return something with size 0.  It will contain at least 1 element.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood the code, but the purpose of `lottotipp` is magic for me.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your Collection doesn't always contain 6 elements, and then your method is called again but the results are never printed.

Easiest solution is to make the method always return 6 elements by adding the integers directly to the set until it has 6 elements.  That way you can throw out the whole boolean kludge.

Also note that you added the elements of the set to the list, sorted the list, but then returned the set.

```
public class Lotto {

    public static Collection<Integer> tippen() {
        TreeSet<Integer> lottotipp = new TreeSet<>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        while (lottotipp.size() < 6) {
            lottotipp.add(rand.nextInt(50) + 1);
        }

        return lottotipp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Integer> zahlen = tippen();
        System.out.println("Ihr Tipp: " + zahlen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arjan, nice solution and explanation!

Comment: Hey Arjan, can i also just use TreeSet instead of LinkedHashSet?

Comment: @svb Sure, see updated answer.  Also check out this [Java Collection Matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JSBPho-Df_1Km0SxXfjW8a8PRLLTeoDDiY8ePs_Ac-c/pub).  When in doubt, just try :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I gave an else instruction that the method should then be executed again.

`tippen` is executed again, yes; but `tippen` doesn't have any output. You also don't use the result of `tippen` for anything the second time you call it.

If you want to run the *whole thing* again, re-run `main`, not `tippen`. (Probably by putting all of the code from `main` into a new function that doesn't take any parameters.)

---

Separately: If you want an `int`, I suggest creating a `Random` instance and using `nextInt`, rather than using `Math.random` to get a `double`, multiplying the `double`, adding 1 to it, and then coercing it to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your random (casted to int) sometimes returns the same value twice (or more)..

```
(int) (Math.random()*49+1)
```

Then, you remove the duplicates with LinkedHashSet, so the size aint 6 anymore.

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer> lottotipp = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(liste);
```

**Your "else" fixes that by calling the method again, but it does not print the output.**

If you run it many many times, it will sometimes print the output, sometimes not...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to print your tipps();
Just print it:

```
System.out.println(tippen());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to that if the size of `zahlen` is not 6, you invoke the `tippen()` method but it's not assigned to any object.
I added a `do{}while();` block that is executed until the size of `zahlen` is 6.

```
public class Lotto {
public static Collection<Integer> tippen() {
    List<Integer> liste = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (liste.size() < 6) {
        liste.add((int) (Math.random()*49+1));
    }       

    Collections.sort(liste);

    LinkedHashSet<Integer> lottotipp = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(liste);
    liste.clear();
    liste.addAll(lottotipp);

    return lottotipp;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Collection<Integer> zahlen = tippen();

    do{
    if (zahlen.size() == 6) {   
        System.out.println("Ihr Tipp: " + zahlen);
    } else {
        zahlen = (tippen());
    }
    }while(zahlen.size() != 6);

}
}
```

If you want your program to print the numbers even if they are not six, you can do this:

```
if (zahlen.size() == 6) {   
    System.out.println("Ihr Tipp: " + zahlen);
} else {
    System.out.println("Ihr tipp: " + tippen());
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much, i now solved it like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lotto {
    public static Collection<Integer> tippen() {
        List<Integer> liste = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (liste.size() < 6) {
            liste.add((int) (Math.random()*49+1));
        }       

        Collections.sort(liste);

        LinkedHashSet<Integer> lottotipp = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(liste);
        liste.clear();
        liste.addAll(lottotipp);

        return lottotipp;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Collection<Integer> zahlen = tippen();

        while(zahlen.size() != 6){
            zahlen = (tippen());
        }   
        System.out.println("Ihr Tipp: " + zahlen);
    }   
}
```

Comment: It still contains a bug, and is doing unnecessary looping.  See my [answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37775079/6178459).